# Why should I use DDEV only for local development?

Tags: typo3, ddev

As mentioned in the documentation of TYPO3, "DDEV is used for local development only" when installing TYPO3 with DDEV. [TYPO3 Docs - Installation ddev](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/Installation/TutorialDdev.html)

There is not really an explanation, why I should not run DDEV and TYPO3 on a production server. So my question is, why should I use DDEV only for local development?

I used DDEV for a local TYPO3, but now I wonder if I have to install TYPO3 in a different way on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DDEV is meant to be for local development and not for use as public hosting.

Even though it is not recommended you can use it in some cases like pointed out in the [official DDEV documentation](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/details/alternate-uses/#casual-hosting).

They state:

> **Experimental Feature!**
> **This is not a replacement for scalable, managed hosting. It’s unknown how much traffic it can handle in a given environment.**
>
> One of DDEV’s experimental features is lightweight hosting with Let’s Encrypt for HTTPS support. You can run DDEV on a public web server, point DNS to it, and use it as a limited hosting environment.
>
> This may be appropriate for small or abandoned sites that have special requirements like old versions of PHP that aren’t supported elsewhere.

And there should be no need to install TYPO3 on the server itself. Instead you should consider to [deploy TYPO3](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/Installation/DeployTYPO3.html).

Comment: I do in fact use the Casual Hosting technique for the few small sites I maintain, and it has worked perfectly. But the docs explain what the issues could be, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/details/alternate-uses/#casual-hosting